# Shallow update not allowed al empujar un clonado repositorio

Tags: git, github

Acabo de modificar un repositorio que cloné de GitHub. Pero no puedo introducirlo en mi cuenta de GitHub. De hecho, cuando lo empujaste, recibí un error "actualización superficial no permitida" `Shallow update not allowed`:

```
(venv) C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\twint>git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   twint/storage/mongodb.py

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   twint/cli.py
        modified:   twint/config.py
        modified:   twint/output.py
        modified:   twint/run.py
        modified:   twint/storage/mongodb.py
        modified:   twint/url.py


(venv) C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\twint>git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/twintproject/twint.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/twintproject/twint.git (push)

(venv) C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\twint>git remote rm origin

(venv) C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\twint>git remote add origin https://github.com/antoinecomp/twint.git

(venv) C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\twint>git branch -M main

(venv) C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\twint>git push -u origin main
Enumerating objects: 46, done.
Counting objects: 100% (46/46), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (40/40), done.
Writing objects: 100% (46/46), 43.07 KiB | 2.39 MiB/s, done.
Total 46 (delta 3), reused 46 (delta 3), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (3/3), done.
To https://github.com/antoinecomp/twint.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (shallow update not allowed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/antoinecomp/twint.git'
```

Aqui estan las origins:

```
(venv) C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\twint>git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/antoinecomp/twint.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/antoinecomp/twint.git
  HEAD branch: (unknown)
```

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres la historia completa de este repositorio, (incluso las cosas añadidas por tus hermanos), tienes que desproveer tu repositorio. Para hacerlo, necesitarás añadir tu antiguo remote de nuevo.

```
git remote add old <path-to-old-remote>
```

Normalmente es la url del proyecto clonado.

Después de eso usamos git fetch para buscar la historia restante del viejo remoto

```
git fetch --unshallow old
```